# Schema Issues on SQL SERVER 2005

Tags: sql-server

I need to change the schema of all stored procedures and tables from "azamsharp" to "dbo". How can I do this without doing every single TRANSFER manually?

Answer (score 0):

This [page](http://www.logiclabz.com/sql-server/t-sql-to-change-schema-owner-name-in-sql-server.aspx) might help.  It should at least get you on your way.